# ingress google compute cloud ip

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, ingress

I'm trying to setup Ingress to serve from a static IP that I have created with gcloud. However it seems that Ingress does not take that configured one but picks a random new one.

The name of that IP Address is homefully-ingress-root and it is 35.234.83.106. My ingress config looks like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: homefully-ingress
    annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: homefully-ingress-root
    labels:
        app: homefully-ingress
spec:
    # ...
```

The IP it ends up having, however is

```
NAME                HOSTS                       ADDRESS         PORTS     AGE
homefully-ingress   adminpanel.homefully.tech   35.244.164.50   80        12m
```

It seems like the annotation for the homefully-ingress-root ip address is completely ignored. That IP Address also shows up as "unassigned" in the google cloud console.

Can anybody help me understanding the issue here?

Best, Matthias

Comment: Can you mark one of teh answers as correct, so it shows up as answered?

Answer (score 1):

my fault - the ip i had created was *not* a global one.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add more information to what @Matthias-Huttar did, you can reserve two types of external IP addresses:

- A regional IP address which can be used by VM instances with one or more network interfaces or by Network load balancers.
- A global IP address which can be used for global load balancers: HTTP(S), SSL proxy, and TCP proxy.

When you create an [Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#step_3_create_an_ingress_resource) in your cluster, GKE creates an HTTP(S) load balancer and configures it to route traffic to your application.

More information on how to reserving a new static external IP address on the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static).